# Continuity of $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-kx}\sin(kx)}{\ln(k+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

The function
$$
f:x\geq 0\mapsto\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-kx}\sin(kx)}{\ln(k+1)}$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ thanks to normal convergence on $[a,+\infty[$ for every $a>0$ : $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\},\forall a\in\mathbb{R}_+^*,\;\forall x\in[a,+\infty[,\left|\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-kx}\sin(kx)}{\ln(k+1)}\right|\leq \mathrm{e}^{-ak},$$
and $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq 2}\mathrm{e}^{-ak}$ converges. Consequently : $f\in\mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R}_+^*)$.

Numerical computations suggest that $f$ is large and positive for small $x>0$, so I do not think that is $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. But I don't know how to prove it because of the term with $\sin$.

My question is : is the function $f$ continuous at $x=0$ ?

Comment: I don't understand why the topic has been closed. Pearhaps I did not give enough details/computations, or my English is poor, or... ? Please tell me, I try to progress in order to post in a suitable way in MSE. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with you and don't see why this was closed.

Comment: P.Fazioli, thanks for asking.  zhw knows very well why the question was closed, so their reply is rather unhelpful, in terms of helping you to improve the post: There is no context, not enough details.  It reads like a copy and pasted from a text book.  Please read How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|132.0076) for an extensive overview of ways to meet the context requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question, hope that it is improved.

Comment: Glad to have assisted, @P.Fazioli!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{n}$ with $n$ a large positive integer. Then
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - kx} \sin (kx)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  + \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}} .
$$
Now
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  \ge \frac{n}{{\log (n + 1)}}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}  = K\frac{n}{{\log (n+1)}}(1+o(1)).
$$
for large $n$, where $K= \int_0^1 {e^{ - x} \sin xdx}=0.24 \ldots$. Also, since $\sin x>0$ for $0<x<3$,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  \ge 0 + \sum\limits_{k = 3n}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}} .
$$
Now
\begin{align*}
\left| {\sum\limits_{k = 3n}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} \sin (k/n)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}} } \right| & \le \sum\limits_{k = 3n}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} }}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  \sim \int_{3n}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t/n} }}{{\log (t + 1)}}dt} 
\\ &
 \le n\int_3^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{\log n + \log t}}dt}  \sim \frac{n}{{\log n}}\int_3^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} dt} \\ & < 0.05\frac{n}{{\log n}}
\end{align*}
for large $n$. Thus, if $x=\frac{1}{n}$,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - kx} \sin (kx)}}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  \ge c\frac{n}{{\log n}}(1 + o(1))
$$
with some $c>0$ and large $n$. Consequently, the function cannot be continuous at $x=0$, since along the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ its value diverges to $+\infty$, whereas the value of the function at $x=0$ is $0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the equivalence between the sum from $3n$ to $+\infty$ and the integral please?

Comment: Sure. Because of monotonicity, $$
\int_{3n}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ -t/n} }}{{\log (t + 1)}}dt}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 3n}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - k/n} }}{{\log (k + 1)}}}  \le \frac{{e^{ - 3} }}{{\log (3n + 1)}} + \int_{3n}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t/n} }}{{\log (t+ 1)}}dt} 
$$ and the integrals are of size $\frac{n}{\log n}$.

Comment: Thanks for completing the argument!

Comment: Great job, thank you. I didn't know how to express that the function is large when $x>0$ is small. Do you think that the function tends to $+\infty$ when $x$ tends to $0^+$ ?

Comment: @P.Fazioli Thank you. I suspect that it tends to $+\infty$ as $x\to 0+$.

Comment: Gary, please be advised of the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1.)  And yes, it applies to your answer here to the question you answered upon your posting.

Answer (score 0):

as $k\to \infty$ :

$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{e^{-kx}\sin(kx)}{\ln(k +1)} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{e^{kx}\ln(k +1)}$

You have exponential multiplied by logarithm as denominator (which will make it very big as $k\to \infty$, but Trigonometric function is not defined at $\infty$.

The conclusion : $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{-kx}\sin(kx)}{\ln(k+1)}$ has discontinuity at $x=0$ as $k\to \infty$

Sorry if it's very simple, i'm very new in here. I'm glad if it's helpful

Comment: I do not understand the way you reach your conclusion. Also, shouldn't it be $k\to \infty$ instead of $k\to 0$? Where do you close your parentheses?

Comment: it is $k\to \infty$, and it is $x\to 0$ not k

Comment: sorry for the typo

Comment: and as for the limit, it's because trig function is not really defined as the input goes to infinity, which make it oscillating value

Comment: As long as $x>0$, it does not matter that the $\sin$ does not have a limit. It is bounded and is divided by something that tends to $+\infty$ as $k\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the link between the continuity and the fact that $\sin(t)$ has no limit when $t\rightarrow +\infty$. For instance $\frac{\sin(n)}n$ tends to $0$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$. However $\sin(n)$ has no limit when $n\rightarrow +\infty$